# TypeScript compiler reports issues at invalid places

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

Whole main.ts:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

// depending on the env mode, enable prod mode or add debugging modules
if (process.env.ENV === 'build') {
  enableProdMode();
}

export function main() {
  return platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
}

if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
  main();
} else {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', main);
}
```

Some errors (not all):

```
[default] /xxx/src/main.ts:11:96
    Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type.
...
[default] /xxx/src/main.ts:11:853
    Parameter 'store' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Reported positions (e.g. 11:96, 11:853) are useless - there is nothing there. What am I supposed to do with such badly reported errors? How can I find real position of these errors? How to fix it, so it reports correctly?

I am using this seed - https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack/ (I think the main file is unmodified).

---

I have added following to `tsconfig.json`:

```
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
```

Please note I want all those checks.

It is also strange, that it reports identifiers that are not in my code. E.g.:

```
Parameter 'dependencies' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

Because of this and high numbers in errors I am starting to suspect it reports errors either in libraries (which is strange, since I have `skipLibCheck`) or in concatenated result file (which is also strange, since everything is being compiled to es5). But I have no experience with TypeScript compiler or Webpack, so I can't really tell.

---

Edit1: After asking at TypeScript repo it's clear that compiler works fine. Culprit seens to be either the TS loader or webpack itself.

Edit2: It's over a month and webpack guys [doesn't seem to be doing anything](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3274) about it :(.

Answer (score 0):

That is because in your `tsconfig.json` there is a property called
`"noImplicitAny": true`.

You have two options:

1. either set it to false
2. declare the return type on every function (the return type may be `any`)

Comment: I have added return to that one function in `main.ts`, but nothing changed. While you are probably right about `noImplicitAny`, I do not want to disable it. I want proper error reporting which reports correct positions. I'll more info to the question, maybe it will help narrow the issue.